# need to send multimap from java to javascript in json

Tags: java, json

I am looking for suggestions on how best to send multimap values from java to javascript in json format.  Besides using an object with a key field and an arraylist, are there any other options I could explore to send multimap values in json format for processing in javascript on the browser? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend on processing all the values you might just want to send it as a list of pairs.

Otherwise then that map to lists is your friend.

Some code for clarity.

```
// list of pairs
[["key1", "val11"],
 ["key1", "val12"] .....]

// map to lists
{ "key1": ["val11", "val12"], ...... }
```

Comment: +1 for responding - thinking of going with map with lists as I originally intended.  Will accept this if nothing more useful pops up.